# pattern to extract linkedin username from text

Tags: regex, python-re

I am trying to extract linkedin url that is written in this format,

```
text = "patra 12 EXPERIENCE in / in/sambhu-patra-49b4759/ 2020 - Now O Skin Curate Research Pvt Ltd Embedded System Developer, WB 0 /bindasssambhul O SKILLS LANGUAGES Arduino English Raspberry Pi Movidius Hindi Bengali ICS Intel Compute Stick PCB Design Python UI Design using Tkinter HOBBIES HTML iti CSS G JavaScript JQuery IOT\n"


pattern = \/?in\/.+\/?\s+
```

I need to extract this `in/sambhu-patra-49b255129/` from the any noisy text like the one above,

It's a linkedin url written in short form.

My pattern is not working

Comment: Can you provide a few different examples? Or is it just the 6th term of a split by space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
m = re.search(r'\bin\s*/\s*(\S+)', text)
if m:
  print(m.group(1))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dAFf7i/1/).

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `in` - a preposition `in`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `/` - a `/` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Another option matching word characters, optionally repeated by a `-` and word characters with an optional `/` at the end:

```
(?<!\S)in/\w+(?:-\w+)*/?
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the left
- `in/` Match literally
- `\w+(?:-\w+)*` match 1+ word chars, optionally repeated by `-` and 1+ word chars
- `/?` Match optional `/`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HR3B6c/1)

```
import re
s = ("patra 12 EXPERIENCE in / in/sambhu-patra-49b4759/ 2020 - Now O Skin Curate Research Pvt Ltd Embedded System Developer, WB 0 /bindasssambhul O SKILLS LANGUAGES Arduino English Raspberry Pi Movidius Hindi Bengali ICS Intel Compute Stick PCB Design Python UI Design using Tkinter HOBBIES HTML iti CSS G JavaScript JQuery IOT")
m = re.search(r"(?<!\S)in/\w+(?:-\w+)*/?", s)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

Output

```
in/sambhu-patra-49b4759/
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
text.split(" ")[5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without using any regex:

```sh
>>> text = "patra 12 EXPERIENCE in / in/sambhu-patra-49b4759/ 2020 - Now O Skin Curate Research Pvt Ltd Embedded System Developer, WB 0 /bindasssambhul O SKILLS LANGUAGES Arduino English Raspberry Pi Movidius Hindi Bengali ICS Intel Compute Stick PCB Design Python UI Design using Tkinter HOBBIES HTML iti CSS G JavaScript JQuery IOT\n"
>>> s = text[text.find(' in/')+1:]
>>> print (s[0:s.find(' ')])
in/sambhu-patra-49b4759/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the ways.

```
regex = re.compile("\/\s?in\/(.*?)\/")
def check(str):
    search = re.search(regex, str)
    if search is not None:
        print(search.group(1))
```

Output

```
sambhu-patra-49b4759
```